# Azure function app blob trigger cannot upload file

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-blob-trigger

I've created a blob trigger that accepts a file from a blob, unzips it and moves it to another blob using streams.

My code looks like this

```
[FunctionName("Requests")]
[StorageAccount("samplecontainer")]
public static void Run([BlobTrigger("incoming/{name}")]Stream myBlob,
    [Blob("processing/{name}.xml", FileAccess.Write)] TextWriter output,
    string name, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
    string returnValue;

    using (Stream blob = myBlob)
    {
        using (GZipStream decompressionStream = new GZipStream(blob, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            log.LogInformation($"Unzipping file");
            name = name.Replace(".gz", "");
            var content = String.Empty;
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(decompressionStream))
            {
                content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();

            }
            returnValue = content;
        }
    }
    log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function finished processing blob\n Name:{name} \n Now writing to xml");
    output.WriteLine(returnValue);
}
```

This will in fact work while running this locally using "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true" in my local.settings.json file.

However, once I've deployed this app and upload a file to the real container using Azure Storage Explorer nothing happens and the activity log shows that the operation failed in Write.Tiny.txt.gz, Could not find file 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\Requests\tiny.txt.gz'.

I have http triggers that do work, and I have tried turning off the configuration WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE to no effect. Am I maybe missing some setting or config?
When I console into this path in the function app and cat the function.json I get this:

```
{
  "generatedBy": "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions-1.0.29",
  "configurationSource": "attributes",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "connection": "samplecontainer",
      "path": "incoming/{name}",
      "name": "myBlob"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false,
  "scriptFile": "../bin/azure-functions.dll",
  "entryPoint": "Requests.Run"
}
```

Comment: The value you use for `[StorageAccount]`, `samplecontainer`, does this match an application setting named exactly `samplecontainer` or `AzureWebJobssamplecontainer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fully believe I also needed Bowman Zhu's answer for this to work, but in my specific case I had forgotten to add the storage account as a connection string in my appSettings.json, as we had recently updated to Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage version 3 and this was our first blob trigger.

In appSettings.json:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "{endpoint}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear that you finally solved this problem.:)

Answer (score 2):

OK, I can reproduce your problem.

Since you can work on local, then it should be no problem about your code.

I can explain why this happened. Your function app on azure don't have the RBAC that can write data to azure blob storage.

Below steps can solve the problem:

First, create identity of your function app.

[image]

Second, add RBAC role of your function app to storage account.

[image]

By the way, the above settings will not take effect immediately, you need to wait a few minutes for it to take effect.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve my problem